# Possible consequences of bugging in game

Tags: common-law

Is it possible to suffer any consequences for the using bugs or programs that use these bugs, in multiplayer game where enter usually 20 - 60 players at the same time? Headquarter of the company is in another country. These are ordinary bugs, without breaking into server.

Comment: What did you agree to in the end user license agreement?

Comment: Are you playing for a price money or a price of non-negligible value?

Comment: @user662852 - There is more to things than simply agreeing to a EULA or License agreement. Especially when the agreement is hidden or there is no way to proceed with being forced to agree. In the US, there must also be a *"meeting of the minds"*. Also see [How Zappos' User Agreement Failed In Court and Left Zappos Legally Naked](https://www.forbes.com/sites/ericgoldman/2012/10/10/how-zappos-user-agreement-failed-in-court-and-left-zappos-legally-naked/#670926273e31).